# How can I take max value from some list but with some conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
list1 = [140,232,857,273,405,374,1234,394,1803]
u = 0
b = 4
for i in list1[u:b]
   u+= 4
   u+= 4
   print(max(i))
```

Now I wanna take the max value from that list but only from list1[0:4] and continue with that.
Now I want to do something like it on this code:

```
for im in images:
      ww, hh = zip(*(im.size for im in images))
      www, hhh = im.size
      max_h = max(hh)
      y_test = []
      try:
        new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,y))
        with open('x.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(str(x_offset) + "\n")
        with open('y.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(str(y) + "\n")
        with open('w.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(str(www) + "\n")
        with open('h.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(str(hhh) + "\n")
        x_offset += im.size[0]
        if x_offset > int(q_w) - www:
            print(max(hh))
            x_offset =0
            y += max(hhh)
            if hh < y:
                y += hhh
            if hh > y:
                y -= hhh
            else:
                y += max_h


      except:
          continue
```

if x_offset > int(q_w) - www then I want to take the max value of hhh until here.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that we apply `max( ... )` to a sequence,
rather than to a single scalar value,
e.g. `max([6, 7, 8])` rather than `max(4)`.

That first example was unclear.
I think your intent is to run a window of size `k=4` over the list
and display local maxima.
A more natural way to express that, without incrementing `u` inside the loop,
would be:

```
for i in range(len(list1) - k):
    window = list1[i : i + k]
    print(i, max(window))
```

A very similar approach would apply to your second example.
Phrase the `for` loop in this way, and slice off `k` elements:

```
for i, im in enumerate(images):
    if i + k < len(images):
        window = images[i : i + k]
    ...
```

After that you're on your own,
do something useful with `window`,
as your question was unclear on details of what you want.

You wrote this line within the loop:

> ```
>    ww, hh = zip(*(im.size for im in images))
> ```

It computes the same thing each time, so to make things quicker
it belongs outside the loop.
Additionally, it trashes the `im` iteration variable,
so for the rest of the loop `im` is a constant value,
it is always the *last* element of `images`.
This seems Bad, it's probably not what you wanted.

Similarly, this is a constant
which could be hoisted outside the loop:

> ```
>    max_h = max(hh)
> ```

Also, your `except: continue` is correct,
but `except: pass` would be the more usual idiom,
expressing the intent to simply ignore the exception.
No statements follow it in the code you posted,
so both would work out the same.
Understand that `continue` would skip to top-of-loop,
skipping the following statements if there were any.